# Can Function.prototype.call be overloaded to log all function calls?

Tags: javascript, debugging, prototype

I've try to change Function.prototype.call to console.log all functions calls (for debugging), but my browser crashed, is it possible? If yes how the code should look like?

I've try to do something like this:

```
(function(call) {
  Function.prototype.call = function() {
    console.log(this);
    call.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(Function.prototype.call);
```

but got lots of `toString() { [Native code] }` when I move the mouse over the page, and I needed to kill that tab were I call that code.

Comment: You are swallowing the return value

Comment: There's a flaw in your premises : the `Function.prototype.call` function isn't called each time a function is called. But I see no crash : http://jsbin.com/kulimaxu/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr;**
No, it's not possible to intercept **every** function call by some sort of universal getter.

`Function.prototype.call` is not called each time you call a function, but is used to pass another `thisArg` when calling a function, meaning it's not implicitly called when invoking a function.

---

The nearest you could get would be iterating over all globally accessible functions or an array of references to functions you're interested in, and patching each and every one.

However, this also implies that you can only intercept those functions, you already know about.
If a function is not globally accessible, e.g. contained in a Lexical Environment, hidden from your code, or was declared after your function ran, you won't catch it.

So while you can override a single function, or define a getter for it, it's unfortunately not possible to generally intercept every function call.

If you, however want to catch all functions called via `Function.prototype.call` you can indeed override it.

There are 2 things you would need to change, in order for this to work.

1. Since you pass an object (`this`) to console.log, `Object.prototype.toString` gets `call`ed with that object as `thisArg`. And you end up in an infinite loop.
2. You don't return the result of the call to the original `Function.prototype.call` call. Which breaks code that relies on this return value.

Given this, a slightly modified version should log the names of the functions, call is being invoked on.

```
(function(call) {
  Function.prototype.call = function() {
    console.log(this.toString ());
    return call.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(Function.prototype.call);
```

However. It seems you want to catch **any** function, called. This won't be possible this way, only functions, invoked using `Function.prototype.call` can be intercepted.

Comment: Did you manage to intercept any function calls this way ? I didn't and that seems logical : ` Function.prototype.call` doesn't have to be called each time a function is called.

Comment: No, that's obviously not possible, since, as you say, `Function.prototype.call` isn't called if you simplay oinvoke a function.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I've crashed more than one browser with excessive logging... that sounds like a recipe for disaster.

In addition, most (all?) modern browsers make that property read-only to keep a 3rd party script from spying on what is happening on the system.

Your best bet is to use the profiling tools in FireFox or Chrome to track what is happening.

Comment: But are you reproducing this specific crash ? BTW this looks rather like a comment.

Comment: @dystroy Mostly a comment, but the fact that `call` is usually read-only makes this an answer of 'you can't do that.'